# Stream transformer from async generator and options

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

Nodejs streams support generating a transform stream from an async generator function. As the docs state:

> async generators are effectively a first-class language-level stream construct at this point<sup>[1](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#additional-notes)</sup>

```
const tf = stream.Duplex.from(async function* (source) {
  for await (const chunk of source)
    yield chunk;
});
```

However, it appears to not support any `options` argument, in contrast to many other stream-construction methods. E.g. `objectMode` is apparently hardcoded to `true`<sup>[2](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/streams/duplexify.js#L90)</sup>, but similar issues arise for e.g. `highWaterMark`. The docs state:

> Attempting to switch an existing stream into object mode is not safe<sup>[3](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#object-mode)</sup>

(nothing about switching it off)

Therefore the missing `options` parameter is confusing to me.

Perhaps there are reasons, why such streams should always be in object-mode, but i don't see them. Similar to e.g. readable streams, a transformer like the following makes perfect sense to me (xor operation for demo purposes, imagine e.g. deflate):

```
const tf = stream.Duplex.from(async function* (source) {
  for await (const chunk of source) {
    for (let i = 0; i < chunk.length; i++) chunk[i] ^= 0x7C;
    yield chunk;
  }
});
```

I couldn't find anything potentially difficult about adding an `options` parameter either. Therefore:

Is there a way to change options when creating streams this way?
(if not, why?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execution path when using `Duplex.from` and `Readable.from` is hardcoded `highWaterMark: 1` and `objectMode: true` in the [node source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/937288aeabf0ad54dcff997f68b5df52bdad0432/lib/internal/streams/from.js#L39). The implementation for how Duplexes are created from various data sources is [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/937288aeabf0ad54dcff997f68b5df52bdad0432/lib/internal/streams/duplexify.js#L57).

Note that using `.from()` does not change that the stream's source is an (async) generator, and generators process one chunk of data at a time and run until yielding. Consequently, setting a `highWaterMark > 1` would be like introducing an array in the generator that preemptively consumes the items to process next. This does not make sense. Instead, generators are expected to sequentially process items from an iterable, one at a time.

The same argument applies to `objectMode: true`. The generator sequentially processes iterable items rather than reading chunks from a byte buffer. The generator receives these items as inputs rather than fetching a chunk of bytes from a buffer.

Thus, for use-cases where the input is a continuous stream of bytes, one may instead use the lower-level APIs `stream.Readable`, `stream.Writable` and `stream.Duplex`.

Comment: Thanks for the viewpoint. However, isn't a `Buffer` already a view on an "array" of bytes, and also what `_transform` would receive? A difference i can see is, that in the classic setup, ["The transform.push() method may be called zero or more times to generate output from a single input chunk"](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#transform_transformchunk-encoding-callback). But for bytestreams, outputting a single concatenated chunk is imho semantically identical. `highWaterMark` accordingly would specify an approximate target size of the internal buffer, in bytes, as intended for bytestreams.

Comment: Yes, I'm with you. A Buffer is a view on a stream of bytes. If the stream is `objectMode: false`, `_read` and `_write` receive instances of `Buffer`. The bottom line is that the current implementation of `Duplex.from` for wrapping generator functions makes it impossible to use `objectMode: false`. However, altering the `highWaterMark` wouldn't make sense for a generator. Instead, one may do the mentioned chunking explicitly in a preceding Transform middleware.

Comment: As a note: I completely overlooked, that streams in object-mode can pipe to non-object-mode streams just fine, as long as the objects are buffers (or presumably strings, utf8arrays, whatever "normal" streams accept). The high-water-mark still counts buffer instances, and doesn't look at the bytelength, which is a slight inconvenience, but as has been discussed, is how it's for some reason implemented.